How can I fix the binding of table to sequence?
I just started using postgresql and I created this table.
CREATE TABLE sys_role (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  title_en varchar(255) NOT NULL
)

Then I found this: Don't use serial. For new applications, identity columns should be used instead. wiki
So I used Navicat Premium Lite to change the column id type to GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY( I don't know what sql statement Navicat actually executes).
But the problem appeared when I realized that there were two sequences.
select schemaname as schema, 
       sequencename as sequence, 
       last_value
from pg_sequences;

they are sys_role_id_seq1 and sys_role_id_seq, When I query the table for the matching sequence:
select pg_get_serial_sequence('public.sys_role', 'id');

output public.sys_role_id_seq, But the actual table binding sequence is sys_role_id_seq1.
I tried the following statement does not work.
ALTER SEQUENCE sys_role_id_seq OWNED BY sys_role.id;

How should I fix my pg_get_serial_sequence query?
And how do I rebind the table to a sequence without the 1 suffix? For example bind table sys_role to sequence sys_role_id_seq.


How should I fix my pg_get_serial_sequence query?

alter sequence public.sys_role_id_seq
  owned by none;

And from this point the function will show the public.sys_role_id_seq1 sequence behind the identity. The serial's sequence was just its first pick, but that newer, identity-related sequence is already owned by the column.
Here's a query you probably issued to get there:
demo at db<>fiddle
alter table sys_role
  alter column id drop default,
  alter column id add generated by default as identity(sequence name public.sys_role_id_seq1);

Omitting the sequence name in parentheses would make it generate that name on its own.
The pg_get_serial_sequence() order/preference isn't clearly stated (it could even look like it's supposed to be opposite), but the doc does say it's either or. Problem is, your id column falls into both groups because it currently is an identity column but it technically also was created using one of the serial types:

pg_get_serial_sequence ( table text, column text ) → text
Returns the name of the sequence associated with a column, or NULL if no sequence is associated with the column. If the column is an identity column, the associated sequence is the sequence internally created for that column. For columns created using one of the serial types (serial, smallserial, bigserial), it is the sequence created for that serial column definition. In the latter case, the association can be modified or removed with ALTER SEQUENCE OWNED BY.


As to "rebinding"

And how do I rebind the table to a sequence without the 1 suffix?

You can't swap or drop the sequence behind identity without dropping the identity. You can't use an existing sequence when setting a column as identity. What you can do is swap the names and sync the new one to start where the old one left off:
alter sequence public.sys_role_id_seq
  rename to sys_role_id_seq_old;
alter sequence public.sys_role_id_seq1
  rename to sys_role_id_seq;
select setval( 'public.sys_role_id_seq'
              ,currval('public.sys_role_id_seq_old'));


alter table sys_role alter column id drop default ... What does the second piece of code do? This sql statement seems to be incorrect and is running with an error.

Using serial simply means you're getting an int column, which gets a default of nextval from the sequence, plus the sequence ownership. The query removes the default expression, leaving it as a plain int, then upgrades it to identity. That's most likely what the "Navicat Premium Lite" did. I attached a demo showing that it all works - if you're trying to run the second query in my answer, it won't work, because Navicat already ran it and that can be done only once. If you wanted to re-do that, you'd now have to drop identity, not just drop default and that error is shown in the demo.
